# SVGs with PNGs inside look blurry on Safari/WebKit browers

Tags: image, svg, png, blurry

I've got a range of SVG images of app icons. Some I've been able to obtain vectors of while others only contain a PNG of the icon inside an SVG wrapper (with other elements like text, etc.).

The SVGs look great on Chrome. However, on Safari and Apple mobile browsers (which use WebKit) the image with the PNG inside it look blurry. How can I fix this?

Here's an example (view the Overcast button): https://podcasts.unimelb.edu.au/podcast/

Comment: You are scaling this image in so many places and in so many ways, disregarding the pixel positions and ratio that it's no surprises antialising algo have difficulties here... Do you really need to include a 3200*3200 raster image inside this 140*50px svg image which will embed the image in a 22*22px rect?

Comment: Yes I agree.  That SVG has a file size of nearly 6MB. If you redraw it as proper vectors, you could probably get it down to less than 1/500th of that size.  In addition you wouldn't be scaling the display size of the image down by a factor of around 1/150.

Comment: @Kaiido Sure, that's a good point. I can reduce the size of the PNG significantly to help with this. In fact, I tested that this morning. But it still shows as blurry on Safari and WebKit browsers. Without having to redraw the PNG as a vector, do you know how to avoid this issue?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Of course. But I don't have the ability to redraw the PNG as a vector. It's not my image and I don't necessarily have access to an SVG of it. How else can I avoid this issue though? Is it just a problem with Safari/WebKit?

Comment: You presumably are permitted to use the image.  Otherwise you wouldn't put it on your site.  I don't see any reason why you could not use a vector editor like Illustrator or Inkscape to recreate their logo as an SVG, if they don't provide it themselves. I have done it in the past with other logos. Icon libraries do it all the time also.

Comment: If you choose not to do that, then don't embed a 3200x3200 bitmap if you are only going to display it at 22x22.  Resize it yourself to 22x22. And when you are happy with how it looks, embed that version in the SVG instead.  Or you may choose to make it 44x44 so it looks better on Mac hidpi screens.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I do have permission to use the image. I don’t really want to recreate it from scratch, however. How do I “embed” an image in an SVG? I’m not familiar with this terminology. I created them in Sketch.

Comment: I just meant replace the extremely large image in your SVG with one resized down to 22x22 or 44x44.  In other words, don't rely on Safaris poor downscaling. Do it yourself so you have some control over what that 22x22 image looks like.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I tried using a 50x50 px PNG in the SVG instead. But it looks identical to the other one on Safari. Any other ideas?